# Disabling buttons in the default ribbon in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbon, disable

I am looking for a solution to **disable the button "Slide Master" in PowerPoint** when someone opens a specific template / PowerPoint file. The reason is to stop basic user to change layouts (basically the master).

The macro I guess, must also allow that specific users (Power Users) are able to enable that button by inserting a passwort. I have nevery programmed anything around the ribbon. Can someone help me with this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can try repurposing the built-in control. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Also you may define the `getEnabled` callback for the button where you can manage the enabled state dynamically. The signature of the `getEnabled` callback looks in the following way:

```
C#: bool GetEnabled(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)

C++: HRESULT GetEnabled([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfEnabled)

Visual Basic: Function GetEnabled(control as IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is described in depth in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)